# Java simplify the syntax

Tags: java

What would be the most terse way in Java to check for the following condition

```
int m, n;
```

The condition to check is whether either m or n are negative but both shouldn't be negative. I'm looking for a terse yet simple syntax

Comment: @euphoria: That won't cope with overflow.

Comment: I know. It's for simple use cases, which I infer it is from the user's question.

Comment: @euphoria: no, it's for cases where the product doesn't overflow, These are no simpler in programming terms than the others. And it gives false positives too.

Comment: Apparently you didn't want the 'most terse' answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(m < 0) ^ (n < 0)
```

Note that in this context, `^` is the *logical XOR operator* (yes, I do mean "logical", distinct from "bitwise").

Comment: xor is a "widely unknown" operand

Comment: That's mostly because people don't know about bits. Which they should.

Comment: @vichle: sure. It was a positive comment

Comment: `^`, I hope, is widely known. It's just rarely of any use.

Comment: Believe me or not, it's not so well known :(

Answer (score 12):

```
(m ^ n) < 0
```

Even more filler to make an appropriate length answer.

Comment: +1: This is terser than my answer, and well-defined in Java (unlike in C).  However, I wouldn't use it, because the intentions are considerably less clear.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - I don't think either is particularly clear, which is true of most bitwise operations.  If this is not a reason for a comment I don't know what is.  8-)

Comment: I would say this is a lot more unclear since it uses a bitwise operator instead of a logical operator.

Comment: @vichle @Oli Charlesworth If the OP wanted clarity he could have written m < 0 != n < 0. He specifically asked for the most terse way. This is it. A comment would resolve the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for:

```
(m < 0) != (n < 0)
```

`!=` operates the same as `^` for `boolean`s, but I think it's easier to understand and more commonly used.

Comment: This is definitely more clear than then the accepted answer, but I cannot upvote since someone gave this answer in the comments on my answer.  Besides, I thought we were going for terse ;-)

Comment: @Robin I see @EJB gives it without parentheses (I wouldn't want to rely upon that sort of operator precedence, although Java is strongly enough typed to make it unambiguous to the normal human). WordNet defines terseness as "a neatly short and concise expressive style". I contend that your solution is not in an expressive style. (BTW: I answered as CW, so no need to worry that upvoting is going to give repjuice to someone undeserving.)

Comment: Hawtin - The free online dictionary-> terse: Brief and to the point; effectively concise  8-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically your test should be - the sign bit (highest order) shound be different.

Here is the test expressed in java;

```
if ( (x & Integer.MIN_VALUE) != (y & Integer.MIN_VALUE) )
    ...
```